# How to show alert message from MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to show alert message in MVC view but it is not showing. Here is what I have tried so far:

In controlller page:

```
if(dataFound)
{
  ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "The search results has been sent.";
}
```

In view page:

```
@if (ViewBag.SuccessMessage != null)
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('@ViewBag.SuccessMessage');
        });
    </script>
}
```

But still not showing any alert on the view page. And I have found by debugging that in the view page it is coming inside the if condition and to the script but still not showing any message. Please advise on this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you debug the client side?

Comment: you have wrap your script tags inside  `text` tags like this `<text><script></script></text>`.

Comment: I have tried it but still the same. Do I need to import any javascript scripts into the page?

Comment: Yes, you probably do, and you definitely need to ***debug the client side***.

Comment: @Amit I am so sorry I am not that familiar with client side debugging.

Comment: You'd do yourself a huge favor if you learn how to view the generated client side script and spot errors there, and even more so if you learn how to debug client side code. Google it. It's a life saver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place it inside a `text` tag:

```
@if (ViewBag.SuccessMessage != null)
{
    <text>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
               alert('@ViewBag.SuccessMessage');
            });
        </script>
    </text>
}
```

For a detailed explanation of `text` tag please have a look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax).

Comment: @barsan My mistake :(. Please try the updated one and let me know.

Comment: I have tried again but still not working. Do I need to import any javascript script into the view?

Comment: No, not at all. It's quite odd. let me try it and I will be back.

Comment: Hey, please have a look here https://dotnetfiddle.net/PUBQ0Y. It works. You might have forgotten to include jquery.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! its working now. Yes I have missed to include the reference to the JQuery. Thank you so much..