# Asp.net mvc controller code method struck

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am relatively new to asp.net mvc but I have worked on asp.net webforms. The issue i am facing is I have button on my view page if I click certain action needs to be done and alert message has to be thrown. I could easily achieve this in asp.net webforms with a onclick event and return back to same page but I am unable to do this asp.net mvc

Action method in controller:

```
  Public  void loaddata()
  {
    //Some logic
    Viewbag.message="success"
  }
```

In view page:

```
  <scripts>
   @if(Viewbag.message!= null)
   {
    //javascript alert box logic
   }
  <scripts>
```

This code works till controller action method but after finishing that it doesn't go to the view where I have the button

Comment: It's almost never a good decision to have `void` actions in ASP.NET MVC. I'd suggest you to read a tutorial on how things are done in MVC. The only way you can put data in the `ViewBag` and have it in the View is to reload the View (normally through `return View()` / `return PartialView()`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show alert message from MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443824/how-to-show-alert-message-from-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Your controllen action is returning void, so nothing goes back to your view.
In MVC this is a bad practice.  If you really don't want to return a view or partialView, you can also return a different type of ActionResult.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Returning a HttpStatusCodeResult or JsonResult might help you in this situation.